# How to exclude shortcode from specific page IDs if it's set to global

Tags: pages, shortcode, tags, exclude

At this moment I am using the code below, to add a shortcode for a table on all the posts and pages, but I would like to exclude few pages and any post with a specific tag. (ex. page ids 10,20 and tag id 30)

I am quite new to all of this, and I am still learning.

```
function my_shortcode_to_a_post( $content ) {
  global $post;
  if( ! $post instanceof WP_Post ) return $content;
  switch( $post->post_type ) {
    case 'post':
      return $content . '[table id=1 /]';
    case 'page':
      return $content . '[table id=1 /]';
    default:
      return $content;
  }
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_shortcode_to_a_post' );
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this and let me know the result

```
function my_shortcode_to_a_post( $content ) {

  global $post;
  $disabled_post_ids = array('20', '31', '35');
  $disabled_tag_ids = array('5', '19', '25');

  $current_post_id = get_the_ID(); // try setting it to $post->ID; if it doesn't work for some reason
  if(in_array($current_post_id, $disabled_post_ids)) {
    return $content;
  }

  $current_post_tags = get_the_tags($current_post_id);

  if($current_post_tags){
    $tags_arr = array();
    foreach ($current_post_tags as $single_tag) {
      $tag_id = $single_tag->term_id;
      if(in_array($tag_id, $disabled_tag_ids)) {
        return $content;
      }
    }
  }

  switch( $post->post_type ) {
    case 'post':
      return $content . '[table id=1 /]';
    case 'page':
      return $content . '[table id=1 /]';
    default:
      return $content;
  }
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_shortcode_to_a_post' );
```